# How to draw lines unaffected by scaling and zooming

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to build an app where user can add various objects (rectangles, circles) and he can use **mouse wheel to zoom**-in and zoom-out.

For this zooming I set up event handler like this:

```
    TheCanvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(options){

        var p = new fabric.Point(
            options.e.clientX,
            options.e.clientY
        );
        var direction = (options.e.deltaY > 0) ? 0.9 : 1.1;
        var newZoom = TheCanvas.getZoom() * direction;

        // restrict too big/small zoom here:
        if ((newZoom > 50) || (newZoom < 0.7)) return false;

        TheCanvas.zoomToPoint( p, newZoom );
    }
```

Everything worked fine until now. Now I want to draw a crosshair over all objects on the canvas. Something like this:

[image]

So I made my own custom object like:

```
CrossHairClass = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {
    strokeDashArray: [1,2], // I want lines to be dashed
    ........
```

My problem is:

When user zooms with the mouse wheel, my cross-hair lines **zoom their thickness too** and also small dashes get bigger. But I don't want that. I want my cross-hair lines be a "hair" lines = ideally 1 pixel thick all the time regardless zoom factor of the canvas. And fine dashed line too.

Render function of my Class:

```
    _render: function (ctx) {

        // I tried it like this
        var zoom = TheCanvas.getZoom();
        var scale = (1/zoom) * 3.333; // with this scale it visually looked the best

        // I have to scale it in X and Y while I want small dashes to stay small and also thickness of the line to stay "hair-line"
        this.scaleX = this.scaleY = scale;

        this.width = CROSSHAIR_SIZE / scale; // my constant from elsewhere

        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();

        // this example is for horizontal line only
        ctx.moveTo(-this.width / 2, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(this.width / 2, 0);
        this._renderStroke(ctx);
    }
```

I tried various combinations of multiplying or dividing by scale factor or zoom factor but if I finally had lines thin, I couldn't keep their size, which must be constant (in pixels) regardless of canvas zoom. Please help.

P.S.: now I got an idea. Maybe I should create another canvas, over my current canvas and draw this crosshair on the upper canvas, which will not zoom?

### EDIT 1

Based on the answer from @andreabogazzi I tried various approaches, but this finally worked out! Thanks! :)

```
_render: function (ctx) {

    var zoom = TheCanvas.getZoom();

    // ctx.save(); // this made no difference

    // ctx.setTransform(1/zoom, 0, 0, 1/zoom, 0, 0); // this didn't work
    this.setTransformMatrix([1/zoom, 0, 0, 1/zoom, 0, 0]);

    ctx.strokStyle = 'red';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-this.widthHalf, 0); // widthHalf computed elsewhere
    ctx.lineTo(this.widthHalf, 0);

    this._renderStroke(ctx); // I use this instead of ctx.stroke() while this ensures my line is still nicely dashed

    // ctx.restore(); // this made no difference
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you created a custom class, you have *to invert the zoom of your canvas* before drawing.

On the `_render` function of your subclass, since you should be positioned in the center of your crosshair, apply a transform matrix of scale type, with scale factor of `1/zoomLevel` and everything should work.

I would say the correct way is:

```
_render: function (ctx) {

    var zoom = TheCanvas.getZoom();

    ctx.save(); // this is done anyway but if you add custom ctx transform is good practice to wrap it in a save/restore couple

    ctx.transform(1/zoom, 0, 0, 1/zoom, 0, 0);
    ctx.strokStyle = 'red';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-this.widthHalf, 0); // widthHalf computed elsewhere
    ctx.lineTo(this.widthHalf, 0);

    this._renderStroke(ctx); // I use this instead of ctx.stroke() while this ensures my line is still nicely dashed
    ctx.restore(); // this is done anyway but if you add custom ctx transform is good practice to wrap it in a save/restore couple
}
```

Now it happens that this object get cached from the fabricJS cache system that will probably create the cache depending on the canvas zoom too.

I have no understanding of the final use of this object, but you should include this calculation also in the cache canvas size calculation.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my **EDIT 1**